# Unable to open view inside ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a tabbed navigation app, however, there are buttons inside the views inflated on the view pager. And when Those buttons are pressed I want it to open another view inside the navigation itself instead of the whole screen.

This is what I'm trying:

```
public void postForm(View view) {
    ViewGroup item = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.vp_horizontal_ntb);
    View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_post_form, null);
    item.addView(child);
}
```

The viewpager name is `vp_horizontal_ntb` and whenever I click the button inside the view I get the following:

```
02-11 11:26:57.286 2295-2295/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mSignal=5 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=4
02-11 11:26:57.395 197-809/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
02-11 11:26:57.395 197-809/? D/audio_hw_primary: disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
02-11 11:26:57.875 776-884/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109]
02-11 11:27:00.916 776-884/? D/ConnectivityService: notifyType CAP_CHANGED for NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 109]
02-11 11:27:01.085 197-809/? D/audio_hw_primary: out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
02-11 11:27:01.095 197-809/? D/audio_hw_primary: select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
02-11 11:27:01.095 197-809/? D/msm8974_platform: platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
02-11 11:27:01.095 197-809/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
02-11 11:27:01.100 197-809/? D/audio_hw_primary: enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
```

Which translates to nothing for me. Just doesn't work and I don't know why.

(This question is an extension of [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146680/opening-new-view-inside-viewpager/42146824#42146824))

Thanks!

Comment: answered your question on the link you mentioned in this question.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but have you seen what I tried and nothing happens? Can you maybe enlighten me?

Comment: For that, I need to know about `postForm` where and when are you calling it?. It would be helpful if you post full code of your function where you are setting adapter.

Comment: Tab #2 opens view #2 on the view pager. There's a button on view #2 that triggers postForm. My idea is to open another view that is not on the tab.